# I recently got a long term Resident Visa for Poland can I transit through Denmark?

Tags: visas, schengen, transit, eu

I am a citizen of Pakistan and I was recently granted a long term visa "type D" National Visa of Poland.

I was wondering can I transit through Denmark or Germany en-route to my host country or do I need a transit/tourist visa from those countries?

With the flights I am looking at it seems like I will have to pass through border control in order to catch a 'domestic' flight to Warsaw either from `CPG` or Frankfurt.

Comment: I think it's different because he doesn't have a Schengen visa - he has a Polish resident visa. The rules may be the same but I sure wouldn't assume that. @saad does your visa say anywhere that it's a Schengen visa?

Comment: Doesn't any national visa count as a Schengen visa, since it is always delivered by a country and not Schengen? I mean, anyway he will only cross the border when entering Copenhagen or Frankfurt. It would be very restrictive otherwise.

Comment: @hippietrail no it doesn't say its a schengen visa it just says issued for Polska I have been given schengen visas before and I know for those your first country should be the one where you get the visa from. I need some clarification asap. I am catching a flight on Saturday for CPG otherwise ill have to change my flight plan accordingly.

Comment: If you found ifnormation for your case on an official website, why do you ask on an unofficial website to non-professional people? This is always strange to me.

Comment: Hi Vince I have edited my statement. I saw a "one line statement" on a EU website a while back but I am not quite sure that's why I am on here seeking everyones adv.

Comment: @SaadSyed: It's always best to include all that kind of information in your question when you ask it. The more effort you put into asking the more effort people will put into answering.

Comment: @Vince: I really don't know and it would not surprise me either way. I would not feel confident in making that assumption if assuming wrong could have negative effects. That could be a good question general question for the site.

Comment: You could call your airline; they may have specific information for you.

Comment: @hippietrail A Polish long-term visa or residence permit (the two are different, but it doesn't matter for this question) *is* a “Schengen visa”. All “Schengen visas” are granted by one of the countries. All “Schengen visas” allow stays for up to three months in any Schengen country.

Comment: @Gilles: OK well that would be a fine answer with some links and details as usual, because it's not obvious, well not to all of us. But it looks like Tor-Einar Jarnbjo may have found a better duplicate in that case.

Comment: So there is no way for any member of Schengen to grant any kind of visa at all that allows a visitor to enter just that country and not the other Schengen member countries? So basically any and every visa issued by any Schengen member country is always also a "Schengen visa"?

Comment: @hippietrail: There are some fine differences to be aware of. For example a type D visa gives the holder more rights in the issuing state than in the other Schengen states, where it only grants rights for transit and short term stays. Each state may also have further national regulations. In Germany, deportation suspensions can be granted to non-EU citizens, who do not fulfill the requirements for a regular residence permit. These are in most cases limited to a specific district and does not allow the holder to travel freely within Germany or to other Schengen states.

Comment: OK so I voted that this is a dupe of the long term German visa question but others said it was a dupe of two other questions `\-:`

Comment: It is definitive not a duplicate of the two other questions, since they deal with type C visa. This question is about a type D visa.

Comment: @hippietrail I think it's possible, there are a few special cases (but this would be yet another situation than a regular type D visa). Also, I think it's somewhat misleading to consider that all residence permits or long-term visas from Schengen countries are “Schengen visas”. They do entitle the holder to visit other Schengen countries but the requirements and regulations are not defined by either the Schengen visa code or the EU court of justice, there are still many national rules about them.